# New in React JS having problem in my new project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**As I'm new in ReactJs and don't no to face the errors of it and get stuck in the problem as I'm trying to make a picture viewer and date Picker in my Project. Please Guide me.. Thanks in Advance**

**Error massage is :**

**Failed to compile.**

./src/App.js
SyntaxError: D:\webapp\src\App.js: Identifier 'React' has already been declared. (2:7)

```
  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
  2 | import React from 'react';
    |        ^
  3 | import './App.css';
  4 | import 'date-fns';
  5 | import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';**






import React, { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'date-fns';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickerUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  KeyboarddatePicker} from '@material-ui/pickers';

  const [selectedDate, setSelectDate] = React.useState(
    new Date("2021-09-11 T 12:00:00")
  )
  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date)
  }

  export class App extends Component{
  state={
    profileImg:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
  }
  imageHandler = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () =>{
      if(reader.readyState === 2){
        this.setState({profileImg: reader.result})
      }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
  };

  render() {
  const{profileImg} = this.state
  return(
    <div className="page">
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="heading">Add your Image</h1>
                <div className="img-holder">
                    <img src={profileImg} alt="" id="img" className="img" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image-upload" id="input" onChange={this.imageHandler} />
                    <div className="label">
          <label className="image-upload" htmlFor="input">
                        <i className="material-icons">add_photo_alternate</i>
                        Choose  your Photo
                    </label>
          </div>
                
            <div className="App"> 
              <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}> 
              <Grid container justify='space-around'>
              <KeyboardDatePicker
                disableToolbar
                variant='inline'
                format='MM/dd/yyy'
                margin='normal'
                id='date-picker'
                label='Date Picker'
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                KeyboardButtonProps={{'aria-label': 'change date'}}
                />
                </Grid> 
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                </div>

        </div>
            </div>
  )
}

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Remove this line.` | import React from 'react';`

Comment: Just import **once** for every function/library/class/file

Answer (score 0):

### **You are having duplicate import of `React`**

**Remove the 2nd line of your code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react';  // <--- REMOVE THIS!
```

Comment: ./src/App.js                                                                                                                                                                 
Module not found: Can't resolve '@date-io/date-fns' in 'D:\webapp\src'

Comment: That's another problem, mate. Try `npm i @date-io/date-fns`

Answer (score 0):

You have imported 2 times react.

Remove the second line of the code, this is sufficient:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Regarding:

> ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve '@date-io/date-fns' in
> 'D:\webapp\src'

Have you installed the dependency ? If not `npm install date-fns`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are importing the react library twice in your file which is producing the error. Try removing the second import line of react from your file and see if that fixes your issue.